# Redux reducer weird behavior?

Tags: redux

Hey guys i wonder why my state is getting undefined after I process through this :

Just want to decrease the like property from 1 do you guys see issues in my nested processing ?

```js
 case "UNLIKE_COMMENT":
      const unLikeIndex = getKeyIndex(
        state.list[action.index],
        action.commentId
      );

      return updateObject(state, {
        isFetching: false,
        list: {
          ...state.list,
          [action.index]: updateValue(unLikeIndex, state.list[action.index], {
            [unLikeIndex]: {
              ...state.list[action.index][unLikeIndex],
              like: state.list[action.index][unLikeIndex].like - 1,
            },
          }),
        },
      });


export const updateObject = (oldObject, newValues) =>
  Object.assign({}, oldObject, newValues);


export const updateValue = (index, state, value) =>
  state.map((item, i) => {
    i === index ? value : item;
  });

// Tested and works
export const getKeyIndex = (array, keyToFind) => {
  let ret = -1;
  array.forEach(({ key }, index) => {
    if (key === keyToFind) ret = index;
  });

  return ret;
};
```

**Before / After processing**

[image: Before / After processing]

Comment: check the type of your list

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I am finding your code incredibly hard to read and there may be more errors than just this one.  But for sure your `updateValue` function is mapping the array to `undefined`.

```
export const updateValue = (index, state, value) =>
  state.map((item, i) => {
    i === index ? value : item;
  });
```

The problem is that you put your map callback inside of curly braces `{}` without a `return` statement.  `map` replaces every element with the returned value, so it replaces every element of the array with `undefined`.

You can either add the word `return`

```
updateValue = (index, state, value) =>
  state.map((item, i) => {
    return i === index ? value : item;
  });
```

Or write it inline without the curly braces

```
updateValue = (index, state, value) =>
  state.map(
    (item, i) => i === index ? value : item
  );
```